# Any way to mitigate the large server load during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE operations?

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm using MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to load csv files, and have noticed that during these loads, server output speed to other users diminishes eg long page download times, logins timeout. The LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE operations themselves are very fast and effective.

What is the best way to approach this type of problem? I'm currently on a reasonably powerful VPS server (operates well when not processing LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE) that contains both the main and mysql server.

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like disk during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. Do you have iostat figures for both times? Is MySQL not the "main" server?

Comment: Is the table(s) you are loading InnoDB or MyISAM? @Vérace Do not discard locking.

Comment: @jynus - it's InnoDB. Does InnoDB not auto lock when inserting? Thank you btw.

Comment: @Vérace - just looking up what iostat means - new term for me. Re MySQL not being the main server, I meant to convey that I don't have two separate physical machines ie one serving MySQL, and the other Apache. Just one machine serving both - I'm sharing a vps machine with a handful of other users. Thanks for your reply too.

Comment: @Vérace - when you say both times, are you referring to the times each csv load start and finish?

Comment: I meant compare iostats (under similar load otherwise) when you are and aren't running the LOAD DATA INFILE. Try to see if you have i/o bottlenecks during the loading process.

Comment: @Shaun On MyISAM, the table is fully locked on LOAD DATA, on InnoDB you can still insert new rows, for example. You may want to have a look at pt-fifo-split http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-fifo-split.html in order to import in chunks, but I would review your server configuration first.